# Sharepoint 2010 Webpart Ajax not working

Tags: web-part, jquery, ajax

I have a custom webpart within Sharepoint and am trying to apply some ajax to the webpart.

The same code works within a .net web application but not within a sharepoint web part.

The code from the .net web application is shown below (the aspx page and the code behind) which works fine.:

**ASPX File**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
    $("#Result").click(function () {
        var loc = window.location.href;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: loc + "/GetMessage",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
        $("#Result").text(msg.d);
      }
    });
  });
});

   </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div id="Result">Click here for the time.</div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</asp:Content>
```

**.CS File**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetMessage()
        {
            return "Codebehind method call...";
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetDate()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The text "Click here for the time" changes to "Code behind method call" when I click on it without doing a postback. I can step into the code and this calls the method GetMessage() in the code behind within a .net web application.

However this does not work on a webpart within sharepoint 2010. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Vinnie,

Did you tried making a separate Web Service for this, as mentioned in the below article:
[AJAX Style Web Parts in SharePoint the Easy Way](http://dbremes.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/ajax-style-web-parts-in-sharepoint-the-easy-way/)

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Arsalan I will try creating a webservice and see if this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I can not put comments, these are some things I would try:

1. change jquery library to a newer version instead of 1.2.6
2. implement ajax error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown), and do some console log or alert message, or use firebug or developer tools to debug.